# Regex + Unable to reject/validate Japanese Character in string

Tags: javascript, regex

Here I am trying to validate/reject a URL in which few of the japanese characters are present.

```
REGEX = /\A(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.\S*)?\z/

example URL - https://お客様固有情報.stestg.jp/
```

Suggest some thing to add in regex to accept only english characters.

Comment: In JavaScript, that is **string**, not regex. See **[mcve]**.

Comment: Replace `\A` with `^`, `\z` with `$`, and escape special characters (like `.` here) correctly. Or use a regex literal. In JS, `\A` and `\z` are not supported, and actually, `$` acts like `\z`.

Comment: using this regex 
`^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.\S*)?$`
no success
trying in a rails application

Comment: This works for Japanese chars as well as normal alpha-numeric `[一-龯a-zA_Z0-9]`

Comment: @shubhangisingh: So, why use JS tag if it is RoR?

Comment: @Lissy i want to reject japanese (all half width and full width ) characters

Comment: Try [`/\Ahttps?:\/\/[\p{L}0-9]+([-.][\p{L}0-9]+)*\.\p{L}{2,}(:[0-‌​9]{1,5})?(\/(?:\.\S*)?)?\z/`](http://rubular.com/r/1lx4zE6aAD) (do not copy from SO comment, only from Rubular).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is in  js file, the application is in ROR

Comment: You need to specify the relevant tags, and if your regex is used by the Onigmo regex engine, you must specify ruby-on-the-rails tag, not JS one.

Comment: What is `(\/.\S*)?` supposed to match? I guess the `.` must match a literal dot and must be escaped. Well, I might misunderstand the whiole question. Look, [your regex does not match the URL you shared.](http://rubular.com/r/72ekWml4T8)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i have checked on rubular, the regex is working fine there, but its not working fine on my application

Comment: It means you did not "code" the regex into your solution correctly. If you are passing a string pattern, you do not need to escape `/` and the leading/trailing `/`s.

Comment: If you still need help, post the exact scenario you have.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i guess you are correct there is some issue in the implementation